# I want to login to a website without using urllib2 and mechanize

Tags: python

I want to login to a website without using urllib2 and mechanize.

I am able to open a  website but I'm not able to login to it programmatically.

Below is the script which opens the website.

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f', 5, autoraise = True)
```

The above code opens StackOverflow page and username and password field will appear. But I'm not getting how to login to it automatically by providing username and password in Python script itself.

Answer (score 0):

[Webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) Module isn't made for this! use the right tool for the job. Mechanize could perhaps do the job. Or the basic [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) python binding, or a higher level API (above selenium) such as provided by [splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/). Any one of those solutions could solve your problems with few lines of python code